# Dynamic data load on scroll in HTML Dropdown

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to achieve data load on scroll down in an HTML Dropdown. My code is below.

**HTML**

```html
 <div class="dropdown d-inline-block">
    <!-- Set to display as inline-block -->
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Select a Record
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="recordDropdown">
        <!-- Records will be dynamically added here -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

But I want to achieve it using HTML dropdown as:

```html
@Html.DropDownList("Customer_1", customersList, new { @class = "form-select form-select-sm", OnChange = "LoadCustomer(1, false)" })
```

**jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var skip = 0;
    var take = 10;
    var recordDropdown = $("#recordDropdown");
    var loadMoreButton = $("#loadMoreButton");
    var records = []; // Store fetched records

    loadMoreButton.click(function () {
        skip += take;
        loadRecords(skip, take);
    });

    function loadRecords(skip, take) {
        if (records.length <= skip) {
            // Fetch records from server only if necessary
            fetchRecords(skip, take);
        } else {
            displayRecords(skip, take);
        }
    }

    function fetchRecords(skip, take) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Customer/GetRecords', // Replace with your actual URL
            type: 'GET',
            data: { skip: skip, take: take },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.result && data.result.length > 0) {
                    records = records.concat(data.result);
                    displayRecords(skip, take);
                } else {
                    loadMoreButton.hide(); // Hide "Load More" button when no more records
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log('Error:', error);
            }
        });
    }

    function displayRecords(skip, take) {
        recordDropdown.empty(); // Clear existing items

        for (var i = skip; i < skip + take && i < records.length; i++) {
            var record = records[i];
            var name = record.lastName + ", " + record.firstName;

            var item = $('<li>', {
                class: 'dropdown-item',
                text: name // Display name
            });

            recordDropdown.append(item);
        }

        if (records.length > skip + take) {
            loadMoreButton.show(); // Show "Load More" button when more records can be loaded
        } else {
            loadMoreButton.hide(); // Hide "Load More" button when no more records
        }
    }

    // Load initial records
    loadRecords(skip, take);
});
```

and lastly here is the method on server side which will get hit from AJAX.

**Controller Method**

```csharp
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetRecords(int skip, int take)
{
    try
    {
        var records = _customerAppService.Value.GetCustomerSimpleListforCombineCust(skip, take).OrderBy(x =>x.LastName).ToList();
        //return Json(new ResponseResultViewModel() { Data = records }.Succeed());
        return Json(records);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogError(ex.Message, ex, this.getActionName(), this.getControllerName());
        return Json(new ResponseResultViewModel(RBCSConsts.JsonFailureMessage).Failure());
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this without button and on scroll down in the dropdown. Firstly it should show 10 records then it should send AJAX request and get next 10 records on scroll down and clears the previous 0-9 records and so on.

**Note:** *My app is in Boilerplate and I am using .NET framework with C# and jQuery for front end.*

Comment: *But I want to achieve it using HTML dropdown* - well, simply: you can't.   `@Html.DropDownList` will create a `<select>` element, but you don't want a `select`, you want `li` elements in your existing `ul`.

Comment: Can a scroll be added in such dropdown with `li` and `ul` and then can we load the data dynamically on scroll down?

Comment: Certainly.  But no change with a `<select>`